# Prepping geodata for interactive geo viz using Bokeh - slow to JSON

Tags: json, visualization, bokeh, geopandas

I'm trying to create a geo viz using this data which maps out all of the zip codes in NYC: https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Health/Modified-Zip-Code-Tabulation-Areas-MODZCTA-Map/5fzm-kpwv. I've used geopandas to read the data as a geodataframe, used shapely.wkt - loads on the multipoloygon, & set the appropriate column as the geometry.

I then uploaded this tree census data (https://data.cityofnewyork.us/Environment/2015-Street-Tree-Census-Tree-Data/uvpi-gqnh) into a df and merged the two on the zipcode column (I renamed cols myself as datasets used different terms).

My goal is to create an interactive geo viz using Bokeh, which I understand uses GEOJson. I've used the following code to achieve: [JNB screenshot of code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slKZN.png)

However, it is taking an exceedingly long time to run the code:
nyc_trees = json.loads(nyc_trees.to_json())

I've tried ujson as well, but it hasn't helped with the timing. Is there a way to speed this up or another work around?

Comment: You can see a fast Bokeh-based polygon rendering for all of the buildings in NYC, which is presumably vastly larger than the number of zip codes in NYC, at https://examples.pyviz.org/nyc_buildings . If you can use that approach, surely it will be very speedy! But note that the example uses data converted to Parquet format, while JSON will be vastly slower, so you'd first need to convert out of JSON (which I know is your bottleneck right now!).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.